# Create lzo file and Lzo index file from raw file in plain Java

Tags: hadoop, compression, lzo

Is there a library I could use to compress a text file to lzo file and also generate it's lzo index file outside hadoop in plain java program ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- So there aren't libraries readily available outside hadoop world to
  create lzo and lzo index files.
- Which basically leaves us to use open
  source projects like hadoop-lzo (calls native c++ lzo library) and
  lzo-java (which contains a java implementation of lzo compression
  also)